# add a local repository as a sub directory of remote repository

Tags: git

suppose I have a remote repository (`git@server:project.git`) with following structure:

```
./client
./server
```

And then I created a local repository in directory `~/myproject/test` using `git init; git add . ; git commit -m "init check in "`. I want to push this local repository to the remote repository as a sub-directory `test`paralleled with `client` and `server` , that is

```
./client
./server
./test
```

I wish all the check-in history in the local could be kept in the remote repository . Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The usual solution is to use a [subtree merge strategy](http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/).

See "[Git subtree merge strategy, possible without merging history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739393/git-subtree-merge-strategy-possible-without-merging-history)" for the details.

---

One other solution would be to declare your local repo as a submodule of your remote repo.

For that, you would need:

- to push your local repo as an independent repo on your remote server
- to clone `git@server:project.git` locally
- add `git@server:test.git` as [a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule)

But if your test files are closely linked  to your project, that is probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers did not work for me (needed more details : Git beginner here ;-), whereas https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules did it perfectly with a step-by-step approach. It also explains both methods to merge / discard history.

Comment: Link is broken as of 2016.03.27.

Comment: Link is OK as of 2017.08.24.